# File (.plist) stored at /Library/MyAppData/userstatus.plist keeps getting deleted in release builds. What's going on?

Tags: iphone, build, plist, release

I'm facing a weird problem here. I'm saving some user information in a file called "userstatus.plist" which is saved in my application's /Library/MyAppData/userstatus.plist folder location.

In my app I check if the file exists using:

```
- (void)checkFile {
    NSString *statusPath = [self statusPath];
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:statusPath]) {
        NSLog(@"Reading user status from file");
        _userStatus = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:statusPath];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Creating new user status");
        _userStatus = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
}

- (NSString*)statusPath {
    return [[self libraryPath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyAppData/userstatus.plist"];
}

- (NSString*)libraryPath {
    NSString* path = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    return path;
}
```

Whenever I test my app in a debug build, I only get the "Creating new user status" message once, on the first build. In subsequent builds I get the "Reading user status from file" message.

However, when I switch to a release build, I keep getting the "Creating new user status" message for every build that I do, essentially wiping out any user data I have stored.

Any help would be much appreciated, since I'm at my wit's end... thanks! :)

EDIT:
I ran the release build on the emulator so I could keep a watch on my finder window to see what's going on in that location (/Library/MyAppData/). Turns out the plist file was never created, which is weird. I do have other files there which get created without any problems. Only the plist file does not get created. Hopefully this should help get a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for wasting anyone's time here. The solution had nothing to do with what I thought while asking the question. During development, I used an `NSAssert` on the line where I write the file to the location; I forgot that `NSAssert`s are skipped in release builds.

Sorry everyone, my bad. I'm leaving this question up, though, if it might help anyone (in whatever way it can).